# Redirect sub-folder to another folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect the content of ***domain.com/app1*** to ***domain.com/apps/app1***, but keep the url ***domain.com/app1***.

How to do that? 
Is it possible to do via *.htaccess* file, or should I modify *httpd.conf* file, add some VirtualHost ...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in http or virtual host config:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?app1(/.*)?$ /apps%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

You may use this rule in site root .htaccess as well.

Comment: That will redirect me to subfolder, but I need to keep original url.

Comment: No this won't redirect, there is no `R` flag here.

Comment: Make sure you test in a new browser or from command line. Is `/apps/app1` a real directory?